# Can you set a value in CSS from another value?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I want to get `#origin`'s background color and set the value for `#reciever`. Is there any way to fetch a value from another element?

```css
#origin {
  background-color:#58ae12;
}
#reciever {
  background-color: /* get value from #origin */
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 0):

In Pure CSS it's not possible.

Here's 3 working solutions

```js
// With Javacript
document.body.querySelector('#inherit-js').style.background = getComputedStyle(document.body.querySelector('#parent-js')).background

// With Javacript hack 
let color = '#123456'; //Set or Get color from anywhere you need
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<style>:root{--color-wanted-hack:${color};}</style>`); //Append style before DOM rendering then css var --color-wanted-hack is set
```

```css
/* With CSS variables */

:root {
  --color-wanted: blue;
}

#parent-var {
  background: var(--color-wanted)
}

#inherit-var {
  color: white;
  background: var(--color-wanted)
}


/* With Javascript */

#parent-js {
  background: red;
}


/* With Javascript hack */

#parent-js-hack {
  background: var(--color-wanted-hack);
}

#inherit-js-hack {
  color: white;
  background: var(--color-wanted-hack)
}
```

```html
<p id="parent-var">Hello world !</p>
<p id="inherit-var">Hello again !</p>

<p id="parent-js">Hello world !</p>
<p id="inherit-js">Hello again !</p>

<p id="parent-js-hack">Hello world !</p>
<p id="inherit-js-hack">Hello again !</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Variables were introduced in 2015 and gained much needed browser support in 2016. I would recommend MDN docs on this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

```css
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #58ae12;
}
```

Then in the #receiver, use that set variable:

```css
#receiver {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

Hope this helps @octa_yt00

Answer (score -1):

You have **3 solutions**

- currentColor
- root Color
- transparent

**currentColor**

```html
<div id="origin">
    <div id="reciever">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#origin {
    background-color: #58ae12;
    color: #58ae12;
}
#reciever {
    background-color: currentColor;
}
```

**:root color**

```css
:root {
    --origin-color: #58ae12;
}

#origin {
    background-color: var(--origin-color);
}
#reciever {
    background-color: var(--origin-color);
}
```

**Transparent**

```html
<div id="origin">
    <div id="reciever">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#origin {
    background-color: #58ae12;
}
#reciever {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use Jquery you can change what you want.

You are looking for the original color

```
var old=$("#origin").css("background-color");
```

and you can change it

```
$("#reciever").css("background-color",old);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's any way to get the background color from another ID directly through CSS. However, you can use variables for this.

For Variables you have to make a root at the start:

```
:root {
    --bgcolor: #58ae12;
}
```

This way you will have a background color variable named **bgcolor**. You can simply use this in your background color then. However, for using it you have to use `var(--bgcolor)`. E.g.

```
#origin {
  background-color:var(--bgcolor);
}
#reciever {
  background-color: var(--bgcolor);
}
```